# Proving an exponential inequality using calculus

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponentiation

> Prove ( using calculus) that $20.17^{20.16}<20.16^{20.17}$.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can probably find a few related posts on this site. You can check, for example, [Fastest way to check if $x^y > y^x$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/517555) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/517555).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the logarithm. Divide each side by $20.16 \times 20.17$. So the question becomes:

> Prove $$ \frac{\ln 20.17}{20.17} < \frac{ \ln 20.16}{20.16}$$

However, the derivative of $ f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is $$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$
From the product rule. So the fucntion $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is decreasing if $x>e$. The result follows as. $$20.17>20.16>e$$As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/proving-mathrm-e-3).