# A sequence with exponential recursive condition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

definition of sequence $a_n$ is in below $$a_{n+1}=a_1^{a_n}$$ if $a_1= \sqrt[3]{3} $
 $a_n $ converge to $l$ ,what is $l$?
I get stuck on this problem , can you help me .

Answer (score 1):

$$\qquad{a_= \sqrt[3]{3} \\n=1\to a_2=a_1^{a_1}\\n=2\to a_3=a_1^{a_2}=a_1^{a_1^{a_1}}\\n=3 \to a_4=a_1^{a_3}=a_1^{a_2}=a_1^{a_1^{a_1^{a_1}}}\\\vdots\\a_n=a_1^{a_1^{a_1^{a_1^{a_1^{a_1^{\cdots}}}}}}}$$suppose $a_1=a$,$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=l$ so 
you will have 
$$\quad{l=\large{a^{a^{a^{a^{...}}}}}}$$ to obtain $l$ take a logarithm of both sides 
$$\quad{\ln l= \ln (\large{a^{a^{a^{a^{...}}}}})\\
\ln l= (\large{a^{a^{a^{a^{...}}}}})\times \ln a\\
\ln l= \underbrace{(\large{a^{a^{a^{a^{...}}}}})}_{l}\times \ln a\\}$$ so 
$$\quad{\frac{\ln l}{l}=\ln a \\\frac{\ln l}{l}=\ln \sqrt[3]{3} \\\frac{\ln l}{l}=\frac{\ln {3}}{3}}$$ hence $$l=3 $$ there is two roots for $$\frac{\ln x}{x}=\frac{\ln 3}{3} $$ but true is $l=3$

Answer (score 1):

Before we can work out any limits, we have to make sure our sequence converges first. To do this, we'll show that it is both bounded and monotone.

**Bounded:** I claim $a_n \leq 3$ for all $n$. $a_1$ is given to be $\sqrt[3]{3}$, which is certainly less than 3, so our base case is done. Say now that $a_n \leq 3$ for all $n$ up to and including $k$. Then by the monotonicity of the exponential function we have
$$a_{k+1} = a_1^{a_k} \leq a_1^3 = 3. $$

**Monotone:** We'll show that $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Since $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is bigger than 1, we have that $a_2 = (\sqrt[3]{3})^{\sqrt[3]{3}} \geq a_1$. Now suppose that $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ for all $n$ up to and including $k$. We then have
$$a_{k+1} - a_k= a_1^{a_k} - a_1^{a_{k-1}} = \sqrt[3]{3}(\sqrt[3]{3}^{a_k - a_{k-1}}-1). $$
By the induction hypothesis, $(a_k - a_{k-1})$ is positive, so $(\sqrt[3]{3}^{a_k - a_{k-1}} - 1)$ is also positive. Thus, $a_{k+1} - a_k$ is positive and our sequence is monotone non-decreasing by induction.

Now as for determining the limit, Khosrotash looks like he's on the right track, but like he said, there are two roots to the equation
$$ \frac{\log x}{x} = \frac{\log 3}{3}.$$
I'm not quite sure how to determine which of the two is correct at the moment. If you can show that $a_N$ is larger than the smaller root for some $N$, then the sequence must converge to the larger root by monotonicity. Just a thought.

EDIT
The limit converges to the smaller root of the aforementioned equation, which is less than 3. In fact, this analysis will *show* that there is such a root. Let's rewrite our definition of $a_{n+1}$:
$$a_{n+1} = 3^{\frac{a_n}{3}}. $$
Define the function $f: (0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x) = x^{1/x}. $$
We then have that $a_{n+1}$ = $[f(3)]^{a_n}$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/116130) is a really cute proof as to why $f$ attains its global maximum of $e^{1/e}$ at $x=e$. Armed with this, we can show by induction that $a_n \leq e$ for all $n$.

$a_1 = \sqrt[3]{3}$ is less than 2, so it must be less than $e$ ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166316) is a calculation that shows that $e$ is between 2 and 3). Now suppose that $a_n \leq e$ for all $n$ up to an including $k$. We then have
$$a_{k+1} = [f(3)]^{a_k} \leq [f(e)]^{a_k} = (e^{1/e})^{a_k} \leq e^1 = e,$$
where the last inequality follows from the inductive hypothesis.

We then have that the sequence converges. By boundedness and monotonicity, it must converge to a number, $L$, that is less than $e$. Furthermore, by 
Khosrotash's argument, $L$ satisfies the equation
$$\frac{\log L}{L} = \frac{\log 3}{3}.$$
Thus, $L$ is a number less than 3 satisfying the above equation.