# Show that $1 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} \le 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, eulers-number-e

How can I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$ is limited this way $1 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} \le 2$. I know that the lower bound is obvious because the sequence of the partial sums is monotone in a crescent way and the first term is $\frac{1}{1!}=1$, for the upper bound I think that maybe $\lim s_n = 2$ with $(s_n)$ being the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$, since this sequence is convergent by the Ratio Test, but how can I prove this?

Comment: use the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational, also the sum is bounded above by $3$ not $2$ and is bounded below by $1$

Comment: See e.g. [Proving $\mathrm e <3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/proving-mathrm-e-3)

Comment: Which is larger. Your sum or 1+1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+... ?

Comment: NB:  the limit of the partial sums is $lim S_n = e - 1$, where e is the Neper number. Just compare with the expansion of $e^x$, so your conjecture that the limit is $2$ does not look correct :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/prove-that-5-2-e-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\mathrm e &lt;3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/proving-mathrm-e-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for $n\geq1$ we have that

$$2^{n-1}\leq n!$$

so

$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\geq\frac{1}{n!}$$

and then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}.$$